# Detecting Variables (Letters) in Variables (Words) with Strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have a  problem where I need to find the amount of letters are in a string. My code (somewhat) works as it can detect if a letter is in the word. However, it can only write one. For example, if I input "Word" as the word and "O" as the letter, it detects that word has 1 "o". However, if I input "Woord", and "O" as the letter, it repeats the loop and doesn't output anything.

```
stop = True

while stop:
    word = raw_input ("Give me a word! ")
    letter = raw_input ("Give me a letter! ")
    count = word.find(letter)
    if count == -1:
        print "The letter,",letter,"is found in the word,",word,"0 times."
        print "Please try again!"
        count = 0
    if count >= 1:
         print "The letter,",letter,"is found in the word,",word,count,"times."
         stop = False
```

Comment: Use word.count(letter), find only returns the index of the letter not the amount.

Comment: My teacher says the word.index() indexes the word. Also, how would I fix this then?

Comment: Index would raise an error if you enter a substring which isnt part of the string while find would return -1. As I said use word.count(letter) instead.

Comment: Yes! It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do:

```
word = raw_input ("Give me a word! ")
letter = raw_input ("Give me a letter! ")
print(word.count(letter))
```

and it will print the frequency of the word

do you want to know why your code is not working or this is good enough?

Comment: You changed word.find into word.count. Is this the only reason why my code wasn't working? Because of the wrong function?

Comment: No, its instead your whole code, these three lines replace your entire code

Comment: Okay. I see. However, the code is actually a block of code that I need to hand it. It needs to loop. And needs to give back a proper sentence. However, please tell me if I have any redundant code that isn't needed under my current parameters. Thanks!